# Passing data from a loop, into a partial on click, in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal

I have a list of items at at `category/1` which are being displayed in a loop and I have a modal which I’m rendering at the bottom of the page with `<%= render "category/update_item_modal" data: {???} %>`

I'm trying to pass data to a modal which will pop up when the button below is clicked:-

`<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#updateItemModal"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit Title</button></a>`

The modal itself:-

```
<div class="modal fade" id="updateItemModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="updateItemModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="updateItemModalLabel">Change Item</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- UPDATE TITLE HERE? -->
        <%= item.title??? %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, when the Edit Title button is clicked on a specific item, I have to pass my the correct item into my `data` label and render stuff from that title in the modal.  What's the best way to do this given my modal is outside of the loop? Do I need some JS here?

P.S. In my controller I have access to `@category` which has around 100 items, i.e. I can't get the specific item from the controller since there are many on the page.

Comment: For example you can add the title as data-attribute to the button. And after clock, read out the information and add it to the modal.
Another way is to make an API request to get this information after click on the button.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way you can use here is ajax request to open the modal, and render the form in edit mode with the help of js.erb file, but that will take one request-response cycle too.

Render Link

```
<%= link_to 'Update Record', edit_item_path(item.id) %>
<div id='renderModal'></div>
```

then create **edit.js.erb**, render your modal partial in div 'renderModal'

```
$('#renderModal').empty().append("<%= j render partial: 'item_edit_modal'%>")
$('#updateItemModal').modal()
```

this is easy and fast in perspective of developer, but there is second approach

if you want to do it in faster way in term of user experience then you should use api to handle this thing. 
when you do it with api then you need to keep reference of your record in button/link , in 'data-id' or any other form so that you can identify that which record need to get updated.